# Can't get data out of service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, callback, angularjs-service

I'm using a service in order to pass data between different instances of an AngularJS controller. I know that this is not the best way to do it but it's the way that fits my case. The problem is that I cannot get data out of that Service.

```
var app = angular.module('MovieApp', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('factMovies', function($resource) { //this returns some movies from MongoDB
  return $resource('/movies');
});

app.service('SnapshotService', function(factMovies) {
  //this is used to pass data to different instances of the same controller
  //omitted getters/setters
  this.snapshots = [];

  this.init = function() {
    var ctrl = this;
    var resp = factMovies.query({}, function() {
      if (resp.error) {
        console.log(resp.error)
      } else {
        tempDataset = []
        //do stuff and put the results in tempDataset
        ctrl.snapshots.push(tempDataset);
        console.log(tempDataset); //prints fine
        return tempDataset;
      }
    });
  };
});

app.controller('TileController', function(SnapshotService) {
  this.dataset = [];
  this.filters = [];
  this.init = function() {
    var ctrl = this;
    var data = SnapshotService.init(function() {
      console.log(ctrl.data); //doesn't even get to the callback function
    });
  };
});
```

I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SnapshotService.init()` doesn't take any parameters - meaning the anonymous function you pass in with the `SnapshotService.init()` call in `TileController` does nothing.

---

What you need to do is add the parameter to the `init` function definition and then call it in the code:

```
app.service('SnapshotService', function(factMovies) {
  //this is used to pass data to different instances of the same controller
  //omitted getters/setters
  this.snapshots = [];

  this.init = function(cb) {
    var ctrl = this;
    var resp = factMovies.query({}, function() {
      if (resp.error) {
        console.log(resp.error)
      } else {
        tempDataset = []
        //do stuff and put the results in tempDataset
        ctrl.snapshots.push(tempDataset);
        console.log(tempDataset); //prints fine
        cb(ctrl.snapshots);
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it made me understand how little I knew about callback functions. I have done my homework and got it to work now!